# Using variable within each function to sort_by

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

At the moment i'm playing around with Rails to get the hang of it and coding in general. Therefore I created my first rails app in which I want to display my games (from the game database) on one of the pages and sort them by a variable calculated within the each function. My view page looks like this (simplified):

```
<% @games.sort_by{|game| ???}.each do |game| %> 

<p>Userexp:      <%= game.userexp1 %></p>
<p>Userexpscore: <% if (game.userexp1 <= 60) %> <%= @UserexpScore = 1 %> 
                 <% elsif (game.userexp1 > 60) %> <%= @UserexpScore = 2 %> = 2 <% end %></p>

<p>Price:     €<%= game.price %></p>
<p>Pricescore: <% if (game.price <= 20) %> <%= @PriceScore = 2 %> 
               <% elsif (game.price > 20) %> <%= @PriceScore = 1 %> <% end %></p>

<p>Finalscore: <%= @FinalScore = @UserexpScore + @PriceScore %></p>

<% end %>
```

I get how i can order them by game.userexp1 or game.price but I can't figure out if it is possible to sort them by @FinalScore (without also putting the userexpscore and pricescore in the database). I was wondering if this is possible and if yes how I can do that.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You could say something like `<% @games.sort_by{|game| game[:created_at]}.each do |game| %>` to sort the games by their **created_at** attribute if the attribute exists.

Comment: Thanks for your quick response but I really would like to sort them by the @Finalscore variable withing the each function. If this is even possible ofcourse.

Comment: You need to do a bit of refactoring. Elaborating an answer...

Comment: Yes, you would want to put the logic for calculating the final_score in the controller, or much better you should move it to your model and save it to the database

and put in a method and then call it by an after create or a before save hook.

`after_create :set_price_score`

`def set_price_score
   if (self.price <= 20) 
     self.price_score = 2 
   elsif (self.price > 20) 
     self.price_score = 1
   end
end`

You should use the snake_case for naming variables and functions like this: variable_name.

Good luck :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

View is not proper place for business logic.

You can move score calculating logic into model, e.g.:

```
class Game < ActiveRecord::Base
  def userexp_score
    userexp1 <= 60 ? 1 : 2
  end

  def price_score
    price <= 20 ? 2 : 1
  end

  def final_score
    userexp_score + price_score
  end
end
```

Then in view

```
<% @games.sort_by(&:final_score).each do |game| %>
  <p>Userexp: <%= game.userexp1 %></p>
  <p>Userexpscore: <%= game.userexp_score %></p>
  <p>Price:     €<%= game.price %></p>
  <p>Pricescore: <%= game.price_score %></p>
  <p>Finalscore: <%= game.final_score %></p>
<% end %>
```

I suggest you read about MVC and separation of concerns

Comment: Thank you for your answer! It did the trick. And I learned a lot from it.

Comment: Nice and clean solution. Therefore I will try to name those `1` and `2` returned by method as some constants. Probably you can also perform sorting on db level?